# How can I put a link around my excerpts in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to put a link around my excerpts like on my titles but i'm getting a parse-error on this line:

```
echo '<div class="excerpt">''<a href="' the_permalink(); '">' . nectar_excerpt($excerpt_length) . '</a></div>';?>
```

Here the whole code of my post-element:

```
<div class="post-header">
    <h3 class="title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h3>
    <span class="meta-author"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> </span>
    <span class="meta-category"> | <?php the_category(', '); ?> </span>
    <span class="meta-comment-count"> | <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>">
        <?php comments_number( esc_html__( 'No Comments','salient'), esc_html__( 'One Comment','salient'), '% '. esc_html__( 'Comments','salient') ); ?></a> 
    </span>
</div>

<?php
    $excerpt_length = ( !empty( $nectar_options['blog_excerpt_length'] ) ) ? 
    intval( $nectar_options['blog_excerpt_length'] ) : 30;
    echo '<div class="excerpt">''<a href="' the_permalink(); '">' . nectar_excerpt($excerpt_length) . '</a></div>';?>
    <div class="meta-tags"> <?php the_tags(''); ?> </div>
    <div class="tags-divider"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, text strings are merged using the dot character. So if you want to connect them together, you should do this:

```
$a = "text1";
$b = "text2";
echo ($a . $b); // prints "text1text2"
```

Or in your case like this:

```
echo "text1" . function() . "text3"; // prints text1text2text3
```

And if you are using function like string, you don't use the ";" character at the end, because it will end the whole line of code.

```
echo "text1" . "text2"; . "text3"; // wrong
echo "text1" . "text2" . "text3"; // correct
echo "text1" . function(); . "text3"; // wrong
echo "text1" . function() . "text3"; // correct
```

So, just add the dots and remove the semicolon, and it should work.

```
echo '<div class="excerpt">' . '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' . nectar_excerpt($excerpt_length) . '</a></div>';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try?

```
echo '<div class="excerpt"><a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' . nectar_excerpt($excerpt_length) . '</a></div>';
```